# Modify all key names in a dictionary in Swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have a json string built from NSJSONSerialization that looks like this :

```
 {
    "credentialMemberControlled" : "",
    "credentialRSVP" : 0,
    "credentialIsCheckedIn" : 0,
    "credentialMember" : {
      "memberEMail" : "",
      "memberJob" : "",
      "memberCompany" : "",
      "memberFirstName" : "test4",
      "memberPhoneNumber" : "",
      "memberLastName" : "test4"
    },
    "credentialTypeName" : "",
    "credentialIsCheckedOut" : 0,
    "credentialComment" : "",
    "credentialHosts" : [
      {
        "hostName" : "testHostName"
      }
    ],
    "credentialCountCheckOut" : 0,
    "credentialCountCheckIn" : 0,
    "credentialId" : "2015081130008",
    "credentialExtensionFields" : [

    ],
    "credentialIsHost" : 0
  }
```

It has been generated from a NSManaged class and a parser wrote by Shoaib.

(I failed to use Hearst ObjectMapper) to map my NSManaged class and its relationships from the beginning)

**Problem is** : I need to change all my ket names to fit my web service that has different key names when it's waiting for son data.

**EDIT 1** :

So i have my NSManaged Class Credential which looks like this :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Credential: NSManagedObject, Mappable {

    @NSManaged var credentialArrivalDate: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialBarCode: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialComment: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialCountCheckIn: Int
    @NSManaged var credentialCountCheckOut: Int
    @NSManaged var credentialDepartureDate: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialId: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialIsArrived: Bool
    @NSManaged var credentialIsCheckedOut: Bool
    @NSManaged var credentialIsHost: Bool
    @NSManaged var credentialLastModificationDate: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialMemberControlled: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialNumberOfPeople: Int
    @NSManaged var credentialRSVP: Int
    @NSManaged var credentialTypeId: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialTypeName: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialZoneId: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialZoneName: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialHosts: Set<Host>?
    @NSManaged var credentialMember: Member
    @NSManaged var credentialExtensionFields: Set<ExtensionFields>?
    @NSManaged var credentialDeltaFirstCheckIn: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialDeltaFirstCheckOut: String?
    @NSManaged var credentialIsCheckedIn: Bool
}
```

I create an insert a new Credential entity like this :

```
// create Credential entity
let newCredential = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Credential", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Credential
```

Then I retrieve some textfields values and provide it to my newCredential :

```
// set credential values
newCredential.setValue(textFieldType.text, forKey: "credentialTypeName")
```

etc.

At some point, I retrieve my "currently-being-created" Credential by its Id :

```
// create a request to fetch the credential
let requestGuest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Credential")

// set a predicate to retrieve the credential according to its Id
requestGuest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "credentialId = %@", newCredential.credentialId!)
// execute request
let fetchedGuest = (managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(requestGuest, error:nil))!

// convert fetched Guest to data
let dataInArr: NSArray = ManagedParser.convertToArray(fetchedGuest)
```

Then I can get a JSON data from that array using NSJSONSerialization :

```
var jsonError : NSError?
jsonCredential = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dataInArr, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &jsonError)
```

And this is how I printed the result in the original post :

```
let stringJSONCredential = NSString(data: jsonCredential!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(stringJSONCredential!)
```

What I need to do is either:

- Find a way to convert (almost) every key to fit the Web Service
- Find a way to map the Credential Entity directly to JSON with frameworks like Hearst-DD ObjectMapper() (which causes me troubles with to-many relationships)

Now I'm stuck even with the dictionary solution because I don't have a native Dictionary type to loop over, just some NSData pretty printed.

Hope the post is more understandable !

**EDIT 2**

Here is the (sample) content of the array that should be mapped before using NSJSONSerialization, as suggested by @vadian :

```
(
        {
        credentialComment = "";
        credentialCountCheckIn = 0;
        credentialCountCheckOut = 0;
        credentialExtensionFields =         (
        );
        credentialHosts =         (
        );
        credentialId = 2015081500280;
        credentialMember =         {
            memberCompany = "";
            memberEMail = "";
            memberFirstName = test6;
            memberJob = "";
            memberLastName = test6;
            memberPhoneNumber = "";
        };
        credentialMemberControlled = "";
        credentialTypeName = "";
    }
)
```

It is still a bit incomplete, meaning that I have more key/values pairs to add afterwards but you've got the idea.

The keys it contains are the ones I need to change to fit my Web Service, and this is where I'm stuck.

Thanks again for your contribution

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: At first I built my JSON Dictionary step by step by retrieving my textfield.text values. Then I Tried to parse my Credential Entity directly to JSON format to have something easier to maintain. That's where Shoaib helped me by sharing a custom parser he wrote. Then, I added ObjectMapper to map my Entities with different names to fit my web service ( see issue here : https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/68#issuecomment-105831195) but I did not get it to work unfortunately. As long as I have a Complete JSON String, I thought it might Be ok to loop over dictionary and update values

Comment: Comment too long sorry- but when I loop I can only find ways to change values, not keys

Comment: My point was: asking "how can I do that" on SO without showing a minimal research effort is frowned upon. All that info you added in the comment is valuable and you should have embedded it in the question (and you still can and should ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. Not recursive, but you've got the idea.

```
typealias SpecialDictionary = [String: AnyObject]

var dictionary: SpecialDictionary = [
    "credentialMemberControlled" : "",
    "credentialRSVP" : 0,
    "credentialIsCheckedIn" : 0,
    "credentialMember" : [
        "memberEMail" : "",
        "memberJob" : "",
        "memberCompany" : "",
        "memberFirstName" : "test4",
        "memberPhoneNumber" : "",
        "memberLastName" : "test4"
    ],
    "credentialTypeName" : "",
    "credentialIsCheckedOut" : 0,
    "credentialComment" : "",
    "credentialHosts" : [
    [
    "hostName" : "testHostName"
    ]
    ],
    "credentialCountCheckOut" : 0,
    "credentialCountCheckIn" : 0,
    "credentialId" : "2015081130008",
    "credentialExtensionFields" : [

    ],
    "credentialIsHost" : 0
]

let keysMapping = [
    "credentialMemberControlled": "memberControlled",
    "credentialRSVP" : "rsvp",
    "credentialIsCheckedIn" : "checkedIn",
]

func processDictionaryForWebservice(dictionary: SpecialDictionary) -> SpecialDictionary {
    var result = SpecialDictionary()
    for element in dictionary {
        let value: AnyObject = element.1
        let key = keysMapping[element.0] ?? element.0
        result[key] = value
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Considering **EDIT 2** of the question

- Create a new file `localizable.strings` if necessary.
- Insert key/value pairs, left side is the current value, right side is the new value, for example

  ```
  "credentialCountCheckIn" = "countCheckIn";
  "credentialCountCheckOut" = "countCheckOut;
  ```
- Use this code assuming `dataInArr` contains an array of dictionaries where the keys of each dictionary have to be mapped.

  ```
  var jsonError : NSError?
  var resultArray = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()
  for aDictionary in dataInArr as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
    var modifiedDictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    for (key, value) in aDictionary {
      modifiedDictionary[NSLocalizedString(key,  comment:"")] = value
    }
    resultArray.append(modifiedDictionary)
  }
  let jsonCredential = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(resultArray, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(), error: &jsonError)
  ```

If no matching key is found in the .strings file, the key is not changed

Comment: Thanks, I actually was wrong when I said that I have a dictionary containing my Json data. In fact I have NSData which is return by the following line :         jsonCredential = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dataInArr, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &jsonError). I couldn't figure out where to go from that, any hint please ?

Comment: In this case the `Dictionary` object `jsonDictionary` is your variable `dataInArr` and you have to do the mapping before the serialization. I edited the post, the `pretty print` is not needed to send the string to the server

Comment: dataInArr is a NSArray that contains the following (sample) values (as an example) : (
        {
        credentialComment = "";
        credentialExtensionFields =         (
        );
        credentialHosts =         (
        );
        credentialId = 2015081500280;
        credentialMember =         {
            memberFirstName = test6;
            memberLastName = test6;
        };
        credentialMemberControlled = "";
        credentialTypeName = "";
    }
) So you're suggesting that I should find a way to map this array before serializing ?

Comment: That's a misunderstanding. The json string in your first post – and as the headline suggests –  is doubtless a dictionary. Update your post to provide the original json structure and describe exactly what you need to be mapped

Comment: The json string in the first post is still a dictionary. You need to map the keys **after** `ManagedParser.convertToArray(fetchedGuest)` and **before** `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject`

Comment: Argh I'm sorry I feel like I'm wasting your time but I don't get it... The Json string in my first post is actually a NSString shaped exactly like a dictionary, but it doesn't mean that it is a Swift dictionary right ?

Comment: There's a general issue to understand. The string in your first post is the **result** of the whole process, it's the serialized string to be sent to the server. You get the data from Core Data and convert it to an `Array` (variable `dataInArr`). If the server expects different keys than provided by CoreData you have to map the keys exactly at this point from `dataInArr`. After that step the array is serialized to a json string and is going to be sent to the server. So the crucial information is the content structure of  `dataInArr` and what keys have to be mapped